# Transformar String em um Array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Com esse `return` estou obtendo a seguinte `string`:

```
return $data.requestSuprimentos.value;
```

**String**

```
[[1, X340H22G, 30000, 3], [2, 64418XL, 32000, 1], [3, X644X11L, 32000, 1], [4, 64018HL, 21000, 1], [5, 12A7610, 32000, 1], [6, SX340H11G, 6000, 2], [7, C930X72G, 53000, 3], [8, C930X73G, 53000, 3], [9, SE352H11L, 9000, 2], [10, Q2612A, 2000, 1], [11, Q7553A, 3000, 1], [12, Q7553X, 7000, 1], [13, C3903A, 4000, 1], [14, C4092A, 2500, 1], [15, Q2613X, 4000, 1], [16, C5240MH, 5000, 5], [17, C5340CX, 7000, 5], [18, C5240KH, 8000, 1], [19, C5340YX, 7000, 5], [20, 12A3160, 20000, 1], [21, 12A7415, 10000, 1], [22, Q5949A, 2500, 1], [23, Q5949X, 6000, 1], [24, 12B0090, 30000, 1], [25, C1823T, 1380, 14], [26, C4810A, 16000, 7], [27, C4844A, 1430, 12], [28, 12A8400, 6000, 1], [29, C4096A, 5000, 1], [30, C7115X, 3500, 1], [31, Q2610A, 6000, 1], [32, C4127X, 10000, 1], [33, 13T0101, 6000, 1], [34, 34018HL, 6000, 1], [35, SE250X22G, 30000, 4], [36, 12A4715, 12000, 1], [37, 2447B003AA, 48000, 1], [38, 1390A003AA, 90000, 1], [39, Q6511A, 6000, 1], [40, C4838A, 580, 14], [41, C4837A, 580, 14], [42, C4836A, 580, 14], [43, C6650FL, 1740, 1], [44, C6578A, 790, 14], [45, C5340MX, 7000, 5], [46, C930H2CG, 24000, 5], [47, C930H2YG, 24000, 5], [48, C930H2KG, 48000, 1], [49, C930H2MG, 24000, 5], [50, X945X2MG, 22000, 5], [51, X945X2YG, 22000, 5], [52, X945X2CG, 22000, 5], [53, X945X2KG, 36000, 1], [54, C5220KS, 3000, 1], [55, TN670, 7500, 1], [56, 113R00635, 24000, 1], [57, C8061X, 10000, 1], [58, TN560, 6500, 1], [59, Q3964A, 30000, 3], [60, 12A6160, 30000, 1], [61, TN570, 6700, 1], [62, TN460, 6000, 1], [63, C4813A, 24000, 7], [64, 2450B003AA, 9500, 5], [65, 2448B003AA, 9500, 5], [66, 2449B003AA, 9500, 5], [67, 12A7400, 3000, 1], [68, C53034X, 20000, 3], [69, 18S0090, 3200, 1], [70, Q2670A, 6000, 1], [71, Q2681A, 6000, 5], [72, Q2682A, 6000, 5], [73, Q2683A, 6000, 5], [74, Q3963A, 4000, 5], [75, E260A11L, 3500, 1], [76, SE450H11L, 11000, 2], [77, C4811A, 24000, 7], [78, C4812A, 24000, 7], [79, Q6511X, 12000, 1], [80, C6578D, 395, 14], [81, SML-D2850B, 5000, 1], [82, 6707A001AC, 9000, 8], [84, C5240CH, 5000, 5], [85, 0387B003AA, 47000, 1], [86, 12A8302, 30000, 3], [87, C5220CS, 3000, 5], [88, C5220YS, 3000, 5], [89, Q3960A, 5000, 1], [90, Q3961A, 4000, 5], [91, Q3962A, 4000, 5], [92, MLT-D209L, 5000, 1], [93, 1007B001AA, 15000, 8], [94, C5220MS, 3000, 5], [95, SCX-D4200A, 3000, 12], [96, C5240YH, 8000, 5], [98, X203A11G, 2500, 1], [99, X463X11G, 15000, 1], [100, Q6000A, 2500, 1], [101, Q6001A, 2000, 5], [102, Q6002A, 2000, 5], [103, Q6003A, 2000, 5], [104, C930X76G, 30000, 9], [105, SX203A11G-6K, 6000, 2], [106, 0250A002ADST, 6000, 8], [107, CARTUCHO HP TESTE, 6000, 12], [108, E460X11L, 15000, 1], [109, T654X11L, 36000, 1], [110, X654X11L, 36000, 1], [111, C544X1KG, 6000, 1], [113, C540X75G, 3600, 9], [114, 0251A001AA, 15000, 8], [115, C540H1YG, 2000, 5], [116, C544X1CG, 4000, 5], [117, C544X1MG, 4000, 5], [118, C544X1YG, 4000, 5], [119, 25A0013, 15000, 8], [120, X203H22G, 25000, 3], [121, MLT-D209L 3K, 3000, 1], [122, T650H11L, 25000, 1], [123, SE260X22G, 30000, 4], [124, C1823DL, 690, 14], [125, Q2613A, 2500, 1], [126, C540X74G, 30000, 3], [127, 51645A, 870, 12], [128, E450A11L, 6000, 1], [129, C736H1KG, 12000, 1], [130, C736H1YG, 10000, 5], [131, C736H1MG, 10000, 5], [132, C736H1CG, 10000, 5], [133, C734X24G, 20000, 3], [134, T654X80G, 36000, 1], [135, W84020H, 30000, 1], [136, C746H1KG, 10000, 5], [137, C748H1CG, 10000, 5], [138, C748H1MG, 10000, 5], [139, C748H1YG, 10000, 5], [140, C734X77G, 25000, 9], [141, SX264H11G, 9000, 2], [142, C734A1KG, 8000, 1], [143, 64480XW, 32000, 1], [144, C52025X, 35000, 9], [145, X748H1MG, 10000, 5], [146, X748H1YG, 10000, 5], [147, 51645GL, 415, 12], [148, 70C8XC0, 4000, 5], [149, 70C8XK0, 8000, 1], [150, 70C8XM0, 4000, 5], [151, 70C8XY0, 4000, 5], [152, X746H1KG, 12000, 12], [153, 52D4H00, 25000, 1], [154, 60F4X00, 20000, 1], [155, 50F0Z00, 60000, 3], [156, 50F4U00, 20000, 1], [157, 50F4X00, 10000, 1], [158, 12A6835, 20000, 1], [159, X748H1CG, 10000, 5], [160, C782X1KG, 15000, 1], [161, 12A5845, 25000, 1], [162, LS64X, 32000, 1], [163, 60FBX00, 20000, 1], [164, 50FBX00, 10000, 1], [165, T654X11B, 36000, 1], [166, X654X11B, 36000, 1], [167, C9381A, 16000, 7], [168, C9382A, 16000, 7], [169, E460X11B, 15000, 1], [170, 64418XB, 32000, 1], [171, 50FBU00, 20000, 1], [172, X463X11B, 15000, 1], [173, 12A7465, 32000, 1], [174, SE352H11B, 9000, 2], [175, 64018HB, 21000, 1], [176, CN053AL, 1000, 12], [177, CN054AL, 825, 14], [178, CN055AL, 825, 14], [179, CN056AL, 825, 14], [180, X644X11B, 32000, 1], [181, E460X80G, 15000, 1], [182, 60FBH00, 10000, 1], [183, 52DBX00, 45000, 1], [184, SE460X11B, 15000, 2], [185, 52D0Z00, 100000, 3], [186, S60FBX00, 20000, 2], [187, ST654X11B, 36000, 2], [188, T650A11B, 7000, 1], [189, ST64038HL, 32000, 2], [190, S50FBX00, 10000, 2], [191, S12A7465, 32000, 2], [192, S50FBU00, 20000, 2], [193, S60F4H00, 10000, 2], [194, S52D4X00, 45000, 2], [195, E260X22G, 30000, 3], [196, C925H2MG, 7500, 14], [197, C925H2YG, 7500, 14], [198, C925H2CG, 7500, 14], [199, C925H2KG, 8500, 14], [200, 60FBX0E, 20000, 1], [201, C925X76G, 30000, 9], [202, SX203H22G, 25000, 4], [203, X264H11G, 9000, 1], [205, T664420 - Amarelo, 6500, 10], [206, T664320 - Magenta, 6500, 10], [207, T664220 - Ciano, 6500, 10], [208, T664120 - Preto, 4000, 10], [209, 64080HW, 21000, 1], [210, 841586, 10000, 1], [211, 841501, 9500, 5], [212, 841503, 9500, 5], [213, 841502, 9500, 5], [214, D0392040, 80000, 3]]
```

Minha necessidade é transformar essa `string` em um `array` para conseguir acessar os índices de cada `subarray` desse `array` principal, por exemplo para pegar o índice 1 do 1º sub array, seria algo como array[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw8Sa.png), algo nesse estilo.

Consegui filtrar melhor o modo como a string esta sendo retornada, agora ela esta assim:

```
[["0250A002ADST"],["T664420 - Amarelo"],["SE260X22G"],["841586"],["C734X24G"],["841501"],["841502"],["841503"],["Q7553A"],["X264H11G"],["E260X22G"],["C540X74G"],["12A8302"],["X203H22G"],["C53034X"],["50F0Z00"],["52D0Z00"],["SX203H22G"],["SE250X22G"],["Q2682A"],["C5340CX"],["C5340YX"],["C5340MX"],["C5240MH"],["C930H2CG"],["C930H2MG"],["C930H2YG"],["X945X2MG"],["X945X2YG"],["C544X1CG"],["C544X1MG"],["C544X1YG"],["2448B003AA"],["2449B003AA"],["2450B003AA"],["Q2681A"],["Q2683A"],["Q3961A"],["Q3962A"],["Q3963A"],["Q6001A"],["Q6002A"],["Q6003A"],["X945X2CG"],["C5220CS"],["C5220MS"],["C5220YS"],["C5240CH"],["C540H1YG"],["C736H1YG"],["C736H1MG"],["C736H1CG"],["70C8XC0"],["70C8XM0"],["70C8XY0"],["C5240YH"],["C748H1YG"],["C748H1MG"],["C748H1CG"],["X748H1CG"],["C746H1KG"],["SE450H11L"],["SX203A11G-6K"],["D0392040"],["SE460X11B"],["S50FBX00"],["ST64038HL"],["ST654X11B"],["SE352H11B"],["T650A11B"],["64080HW"],["Q5949A"],["C5240KH"],["34018HL"],["Q5949X"],["Q6511A"],["Q7553X"],["12A7415"],["64418XL"],["C930H2KG"],["64018HL"],["X644X11L"],["0387B003AA"],["113R00635"],["12A6160"],["18S0090"],["MLT-D209L"],["MLT-D209L 3K"],["Q2613A"],["Q2670A"],["Q3960A"],["Q6000A"],["Q6511X"],["T654X11L"],["12A7400"],["E450A11L"],["E260A11L"],["C5220KS"],["E460X11L"],["T650H11L"],["TN460"],["TN570"],["TN670"],["X463X11G"],["X654X11L"],["SML-D2850B"],["X945X2KG"],["C736H1KG"],["C782X1KG"],["E460X80G"],["LS64X"],["T654X80G"],["12A7465"],["50F4U00"],["50F4X00"],["50FBU00"],["52D4H00"],["60F4X00"],["60FBH00"],["60FBX0E"],["64018HB"],["64418XB"],["E460X11B"],["60FBX00"],["X463X11B"],["X654X11B"],["50FBX00"],["SX264H11G"],["S12A7465"],["S50FBU00"],["X340H22G"],["C930X72G"],["S60FBX00"],["T654X11B"],["X644X11B"],["12A7610"],["S60F4H00"],["X203A11G"],["SE352H11L"],["SX340H11G"],["12A4715"],["12A3160"],["12A8400"],["C4092A"],["TN560"],["C4096A"],["C4127X"],["12B0090"],["1390A003AA"],["13T0101"],["2447B003AA"],["C3903A"],["C6650FL"],["C7115X"],["C8061X"],["Q2610A"],["Q2612A"],["Q2613X"],["S52D4X00"],["Q3964A"],["C930X73G"],["C544X1KG"],["C734A1KG"],["64480XW"],["12A5845"],["12A6835"],["W84020H"],["52DBX00"],["70C8XK0"],["X748H1MG"],["X748H1YG"],["C4810A"],["C4811A"],["C4812A"],["C4813A"],["C9381A"],["C9382A"],["0251A001AA"],["1007B001AA"],["6707A001AC"],["25A0013"],["C540X75G"],["C930X76G"],["C734X77G"],["C52025X"],["C925X76G"],["T664220 - Ciano"],["T664320 - Magenta"],["T664120 - Preto"],["C4844A"],["51645A"],["CARTUCHO HP TESTE"],["SCX-D4200A"],["51645GL"],["CN053AL"],["X746H1KG"],["C6578A"],["C4836A"],["C4837A"],["C4838A"],["C1823T"],["C6578D"],["C1823DL"],["C925H2MG"],["C925H2CG"],["CN054AL"],["CN055AL"],["CN056AL"],["C925H2KG"],["C925H2YG"]]
```

Dai fiz assim para separar essa string:

```
var x = $data.listaSuprimentos.value;
var json = JSON.parse(x);
return json;
```

Porém ela está trazendo o `]["` junto ficando assim no **dropdown**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não podes melhorar a formatação dessa string na origem desse `$data`?

Comment: Como assim @Sergio?

Comment: Se essa string vier do servidor seria melhor converter numa array "a sério" e não numa string que nem formato JSON tem. Pode evitar bugs na conversão via JavaScript.

Comment: Essa string não é um array válido, deveria ser algo como `[1, "X340H22G", 30000, 3]` para usar no `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Nesse caso podes fazer assim: `var json = JSON.parse(x).map(arr => arr[0]);` - é isso que procuras?

Comment: @Sergio funcionou perfeitamente, será que poderia postar uma resposta explicando a mágica? kk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que vejo nessa array `[["0250A002ADST"],["T664420 - Amarelo"]...` cada sub-array tem somente uma string. Assim precisas de mapear essa array para remover cada subarray e deixar no seu lugar a string que ela tem dentro. Ou sej, tendo a sub-array `["0250A002ADST"]` podes extrair essa primeira (e única) posição com `[0]`.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
const json = '[["0250A002ADST"],["T664420 - Amarelo"]]';
const arr = JSON.parse(json);
const strings = arr.map(el => el[0]);
console.log(strings);
```

Comment: Caso cada subarray tivesse 2 indices e eu quisesse pegar o indice 1, eu teria que alterar apenas isso: `const strings = arr.map(el => el[1]);`?

Comment: @R.Santos exato

Answer (score 2):

Tenta melhorar seu retorno e dar Split em algum caractere especifio, mais ou menos assim:

```
 var array = sua_string.split(",");
    var v1 = array[0];
    var v2= array[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Partindo do principio de que a *string* esteja formatada corretamente, você pode *parsear* para JSON:

```js
let str = '[[1, "X340H22G", 30000, 3],[2, "64418XL", 32000,1], [3, "X644X11L", 32000, 1]]';
let json = JSON.parse(str);

// acessar o conteudo de cada subarray
json.forEach((item) => console.log(item[1]));
```

Comment: Editei minha pergunta, será que consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Como você está criando o `dropdown` @R.Santos?

Comment: Eu estou usando uma ferramenta de desenvolvimento de aplicações BPM (BonitaSoft) então eu apenas jogo o conteudo de uma variável para dentro do dropdown e ele faz o resto

Comment: O estranho é que se eu coloco `return json[0]` ele não vem com esses `]["` indesejáveis